# SQL: KEEP Unique value of C1 with Highest value in C2

Tags: sql, teradata

In my two columns of data I would like to keep only the unique values of ColumnOne that have the highest value in ColumnTwo.

For example 
ColumnOne       ColumnTwo

```
2                  6
3                  2
7                  8
2                  7
3                  4
7                  3
```

I would like the results:

ColumnOne       ColumnTwo

```
2                  7
3                  4
7                  8
```

Comment: Is this a simple aggregation with `max()`?

Comment: `select ColumnOne, max(ColumnTwo) from table group by ColumnOne`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a group by statement:

```
select Column1, max(Column2)
  from your_table
 group by Column1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete t1
from myTable t1
left join (select t2.Column1, max(t2.Column2) maxColumn2
           from myTable t2
           group by t2.Column1) tMax
on t1.Column1 = tMax.Column1
and t1.Column2 = tMax.maxColumn2
where tMax.Column1 is null
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query will help you to accomplish your output for tables with huge no. of records:

```
create table table1_new as (select * from table1) with no data;

insert into table1_new
    select columnone, max(columntwo) over(partition by columnone) from table1 group by columnone;
```

Validate data and then interchange table names:

```
drop table table1;
rename table1_new to table1;
```